# Traversing a map

Tags: c++, c++14, traversal, stdmap, std

I am getting an error in this code? Can someone tell the reason? A similar code available on GFG works although.
Attached is the code.
assume the header file `bits/stdc++.h` and `namespace std`.

```
int main()
{
   int n;
   cin >> n;
   map<ll, vector<int>> val;
   ll arr[n] = { 0 };
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)   cin >> arr[i];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)   val[arr[i]].push_back(i);
   for (auto i : val) 
   {
      cout << "Element        Indexes\n";
      cout << val.first << " ----> ";
      for (auto j : val.second)
         cout << j << " ";
      cout << "\n";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Error message

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:15:21: error: ‘class std::map<long long int, std::vector<int> >’ has no member named ‘first’
         cout << val.first << " ----> " ;
                     ^
prog.cpp:16:33: error: ‘class std::map<long long int, std::vector<int> >’ has no member named ‘second’
         for(auto const &j : val.second)        
                                 ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error message says `val` is type of `std::map<ll, std::vector<int>>` has no first and second member, rather the underlining `std::pair<const ll, std::vector<int>>` has those.

Meaning in your first for loop. (assuming that the `ll` is a type alias for `long long`)

```
for (auto i : val) // auto = std::pair<const ll, std::vector<int>>
```

therefor you should have

```
for (const auto& i : val)    // auto = std::pair<const ll, std::vector<int>>

{
    // code
    for (auto j : i.second)  // auto = std::vector<int>
      // code
}
```

Or if you are using [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), you could use [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) for more intuitive

```
for (const auto&[key, valVector] : val)
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
   std::cout << "Element  Indexes\n" << key << " ----> ";
   for (auto j : valVector)
      std::cout << j << "\n";
}
```

---

Remember, [VLAs are not part of standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard), prefer using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

```
std::vector<ll> arr(n);
```

Comment: ok sir you changed it to i.first and i.second I had earlier written in my code val.first and val.second. Found my mistake. Thanks a lot for the help